# What is the best way to treat an out of date community wiki answer?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

In particular I am asking about [What (if any) countries are either open to or have set definitive plans to allow international tourism?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157147/what-if-any-countries-are-either-open-to-or-have-set-definitive-plans-to-allow)

In Mid-May, I asked a question about where one could travel *now* given the COVID-19 pandemic. A community wiki answer was created with the answer at the time of *None*. Some additions were made around the time of asking before the answer became dormant. However, then a lot of things changed in a relatively short period of time without the answer being updated to reflect that. The question remains a relevant question however now the answer is so out of date that it effectively requires re-writing. What is the best way to do that? Some options are:

- Replace the entire content of the wiki answer as a single edit
- Create a new wiki answer and transfer the accepted answer to this new answer
- Something else?

Comment: If an answer is marked "community wiki," by definition it's intended to be edited by people other than the original author in order to keep it up to date. Whether any part of the existing answer should be retained is a judgment call.

Comment: StackExchange staff announced an initiative to address outdated answers on Stack Overflow in early 2021: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project . They are initially laser focussed on StackOverflow, which is not Travel. But solutions may eventually end up here. Thus I leave a link to that initiative, for future readers to follow.

Answer (score 4):

Either. Firstly, do NOT ask a new question (you didn't suggest this but I'm saying it for other readers). It'll get closed as a dupe (correctly).

When answers become wrong or out of date, there are multiple ways of dealing with it.

- downvote the wrong answer, and add a new different answer
- edit the wrong answer to be correct
- add a better answer (if it's kinda ok but could be better)

there's not really any benefit to creating a new wiki answer and copying across. We have edits for this.  Comm wiki means anyone can edit and update. That's what it's for :)

Comment: Unfortunately, 1 and 3 will not have much effect -- voting is mostly done and the new answer will probably stay at the bottom.

Comment: 1 is not a good idea because that penalizes something which was correct at the time.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't know the correct answer and that you don't want to downvote people who kindly spent time providing useful information, you could edit the answer adding a warning that the content is outdated.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is unkind and ineffective to downvote answers which become outdated in the case when the circumstances have changed. Unkind, because those answers were accurate and helpful at the time the question was asked and the answers provided. Ineffective, because the StackExchange machinery ensures that questions only get seen when they are freshly asked. Changes to answers much later are mostly ignored.

SO Travel is especially affected by this, because so much about travel depends on situations and policies about the COVID-19 pandemic. The pandemic keeps changing, the situations and policies keep changing, and both questions and answers rapidly become obsolete.

I believe that SO Travel should come up with a respectful and appreciative way of labelling questions and answers as obsolete, with a date range when they were applicable, and a way of linking to a question which is about the corresponding current situation and policies.

Thus, I respectfully disagree with [Mark Mayo's answer](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6693/3953) of 3 Aug 2020.

Comment: There is potentially lot's of inbound traffic from search engines/searches that would lead people to older questions. That creates problems when those older questions are inaccurate which are part of the reason why StackExchange has a downvote mechanism.